# Many fields to maintain in View for MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm trying to figure out a better way or pattern for getting many user selections and input from a single page using ASP.NET MVC.

***The problem***:  **I have many input fields on a page and i need to store their values in the database.**

*Here is my attempt*:
I have a single page with some partial views. With partial views, i can break it down somewhat.

For the sake of the argument, I have 50 fields on a page. Some of them are drop down lists, some are text input fields, and others are check boxes. Each value is stored in the database as a row and accessible by a unique business key.

For example, in code when accessing my data access entities using Entity Framework:

```
//Grouping of settings for a particular user
var allSettingsForThisUser = myDbContext.USER_SETTINGS_MODEL.Where(u => u.USER_ID == userId);

//Unique settings for a user
var setting1 = allSettingsForThisUser.USER_SETTINGS_MODEL.Where(x => x.BUSINESS_KEY.Equals("FIELD1")).First();
var setting2 = allSettingsForThisUser.USER_SETTINGS_MODEL.Where(x => x.BUSINESS_KEY.Equals("FIELD2")).First();
var setting3 = allSettingsForThisUser.USER_SETTINGS_MODEL.Where(x => x.BUSINESS_KEY.Equals("FIELD3")).First();
```

..

I have setup a view model to hold each setting on the screen in its specific place.

My view model looks like this:

```
public class MyViewModel
{
    //Strongly typed fields for my view
    public USER_SETTINGS_MODEL OrganizationType { get; set; }
    public USER_SETTINGS_MODEL BookletsRequired { get; set; }
    public USER_SETTINGS_MODEL HasGreenPants { get; set; }
    public USER_SETTINGS_MODEL MiddleName { get; set; }
    ...
}
```

This way i'm doing things doesn't seem that efficient.  As a result, for each field, I need to query the database via a specific business key.  Then, i need to assign it to a specific USER_SETTINGS_MODEL strongly typed field.

I have tried using a view model with a collection of entities. In my view, i then use a Linq query pass in business keys in a WHERE condition. The result was a very complex looking view.

***My question is, is there a better way? a better pattern?***

In summary:
- lots of fields to capture and save
- fields are placed in specific places on the screen
- some fields are input boxes, some drop-down lists, some check boxes
- I'm using ASP.NET MVC5, Entity Framework, Linq and the repository pattern for data access

Thanks

Comment: I think your problem is the db design. This comment "Each value is stored in the database as a row and accessible by a unique business key." is alarming to me. It should be each OranizationType(with many fields) is stored in a table and accessed by a primary key etc...

Comment: Kind of like a table that has columns ID, OrganizationType, BookletsRequired, HasGreenPants, MiddleName, etc.  I agree but this means that there would be 50 columns stored in the database table. If we add a field, we have to modify the table schema each time.

Comment: **C Sharper:** You are right. The root of the problem here is the data model. My current data model allows for great flexibility through a very generalized structure. This is at a great cost which makes it challenging to work with and especially makes things tricky when working with strongly typed values in Entity Framework. I've decided to refactor my data into a better model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like there is a need for normalization. Your view-model is a mess because the data is a mess. Try to represent the groups/categories/types of USER_SETTINGS under some particularity, and make Models upon that: "RegionalSettingsModel / ChargingOptionsModel" etc.

You can create also partial views for reading/updating each model and put them all in one view if you need to.

A table in a database can be represented by more than one model.

Also, regarding the lack of columns, you can create stored procedure with the query you need for a particular group of settings... Example

I asume you have:

Table Settings:

```
   USERID - SETTING - VALUE
      1      -   LANG  - ENG
      1      -   CURR  - DOLLAR
```

In order to have an Entity, you can create:

Stored procedure:

```
   GetRegionalSettingsByUserID(Id) as 
     Select LANG, Curr from 
        (select Value from SETTINGS where USERID=Id and Setting="LANG"
           UNION
         select Value from SETTINGS where USERID=Id and Setting="CURR"
        )
```

Comment: Your representation of the data is correct for my situation. It would work to create a view that would simply flip rows with columns. Rows are being used to allow the most flexibility such that fields can be added or removed without a schema change.

Comment: Well, then, many we can say that you can create an Entity Factory implementation with Store Procedures. It looks like that design pattern have an implementation on .Net EF: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/354501/Entity-Factory-Design-Pattern-for-NET.

Comment: The problem really is how I structured my data. Although a flexible structure that allows for fields to be added and removed at will, it makes it really challenging to work. It makes more sense to normalize the data more to represent the data, their meaning and relationships.